# Enable textbox withing a loop when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i enabled my textbox within a loop when it check the checkbox?. Can you help me guys how to do it.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover mt-2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Duties and Responsibilities</th>
                <th>Weight of Duties</th>
                <th>Rate of Department Head</th>
                <th>Remarks</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @for (int x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
            {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="JdDescription" class="form-control" disabled/></td>
                <td><input type="text" readonly name="WeightofDuties" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="RateofHead" class="form-control" disabled/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Remarks" class="form-control" disabled/></td>
            </tr>
                    }

            </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Do you want to enable all `td` textboxes within selected row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the parent `<tr>` element upon clicking a checkbox, then enable text inputs within this `<tr>` node:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
  var disabled = this.checked ? '' : 'disabled';
  $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', disabled);
});
```

This will also disable the input[type=text] fields again upon unchecking the checkbox. If you only want to enable a specific text field, modify the argument of `.find('input[type=text]')` selector accordingly.

If you also want to toggle the `readonly` text field, do it like so:

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="WeightofDuties"]')
       .attr('readonly', !this.checked);
```